# get XPATH for all the nodes

Tags: html, parsing, xpath

Is there a library that can give me the XPATH for all the nodes in an HTML page?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: //node() is the Xpath for all of the nodes.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an exhaustive solution. :)

Comment: @samplebias : JAVA would be better. but I don't mind even if It's PHP or Perl.

Comment: @Steven D. Majewski: No. It isn't.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> is there any library that can give me
>   XPATH for all the nodes in HTML page

**Yes, if this HTML page is a well-formed XML document**.

Depending on what you understand by "node"...

```
//*
```

selects all the elements in the document.

```
/descendant-or-self::node()
```

selects all elements, text nodes, processing instructions, comment nodes, and the root node `/`.

```
//text()
```

selects all text nodes in the document.

```
//comment()
```

selects all comment nodes in the document.

```
//processing-instruction()
```

selects all processing instructions in the document.

```
//@*
```

selects all attribute nodes in the document.

```
//namespace::*
```

selects all namespace nodes in the document.

Finally, you can combine any of the above expressions using the union (`|`) operator.

Thus, I believe that the following expression really selects "all the nodes" of any XML document:

```
/descendant-or-self::node() | //@* | //namespace::*
```

Comment: `//node()` does not select the root because it's expanded to `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::node()`. In fact `node()` pattern doesn't match the document root.

Comment: @Alejandro: Good catch, fixed. As for selecting the document root, it still matches `node()` as in `ancestor::node()` or `self::node()`

Comment: Sorry, I should said _"`node()` as a pattern"_.

Comment: Just found it helpful for Delphi

Answer (score 2):

In case this is helpful for someone else, if you're using python/lxml, you'll first need to have a tree, and then query that tree with the XPATH paths that Dimitre lists above.

To get the tree:

```
import lxml
from lxml import html, etree

your_webpage_string = "<html><head><title>test<body><h1>page title</h3>"
root = lxml.html.fromstring(your_webpage_string)
good_html = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True).strip()
your_tree = etree.fromstring(good_html)
all_xpaths = your_tree.xpath('//*')
```

On the last line, replace '//*' with whatever xpath you want. `all_xpaths` is now a list which looks like this:

```
[<Element html at 0x7ff740b24b90>,
 <Element head at 0x7ff740b24d88>,
 <Element title at 0x7ff740b24dd0>,
 <Element body at 0x7ff740b24e18>,
 <Element h1 at 0x7ff740b24e60>]
```