# XPath to select between two HTML comments?

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, nokogiri, scraper

I have a big HTML page. But I want to select certain nodes using Xpath:

```
<html>
 ........
<!-- begin content -->
 <div>some text</div>
 <div><p>Some more elements</p></div>
<!-- end content -->
.......
</html>
```

I can select HTML after the `<!-- begin content -->` using:

```
"//comment()[. = ' begin content ']/following::*"
```

Also I can select HTML before the `<!-- end content -->` using:

```
"//comment()[. = ' end content ']/preceding::*"
```

But do I have to have XPath to select all the HTML between the two comments?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would look for elements that are preceded by the first comment and followed by the second comment:

```
doc.xpath("//*[preceding::comment()[. = ' begin content ']]
              [following::comment()[. = ' end content ']]")
#=> <div>some text</div>
#=> <div>
#=>   <p>Some more elements</p>
#=> </div>
#=> <p>Some more elements</p>
```

Note that the above gives you *each* element in between. This means that if you iterate through each the returned nodes, you will get some duplicated nested nodes - eg the "Some more elements".

I think you might actually want to just get the top-level nodes in between - ie the siblings of the comments. This can be done using the `preceding/following-sibling` instead.

```
doc.xpath("//*[preceding-sibling::comment()[. = ' begin content ']]
              [following-sibling::comment()[. = ' end content ']]")
#=> <div>some text</div>
#=> <div>
#=>   <p>Some more elements</p>
#=> </div>
```

**Update - Including comments**

Using `//*` only returns element nodes, which does not include comments (and some others). You could change `*` to `node()` to return everything.

```
puts doc.xpath("//node()[preceding-sibling::comment()[. = 'begin content']]
                        [following-sibling::comment()[. = 'end content']]")
#=> 
#=> <!--keywords1: first_keyword-->
#=> 
#=> <div>html</div>
#=>
```

If you just want element nodes and comments (ie not everything), you can use the `self` axis:

```
doc.xpath("//node()[self::* or self::comment()]
                   [preceding-sibling::comment()[. = 'begin content']]
                   [following-sibling::comment()[. = 'end content']]")
#~ #=> <!--keywords1: first_keyword-->
#~ #=> <div>html</div>
```

Comment: Very good answer as usual... :) The last part is the one..probably OP was looking for.

Comment: For the case 
`<title>hello!</title><!--begin content--><!--keywords1: first_keyword--><div>html</div><!--end content-->`
It only gives back `<div>html</div>` any insights into this?. As i need the comment with keywords returned as well.

Comment: The problem is that `//*` select all _element_ nodes. This does not include comments and some others (see this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643323/get-xpath-for-all-the-nodes)). Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JustinKo For the update with comments.