# XPath to select between two HTML comments is not working?

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, nokogiri, scraper

I'm trying to select some content between two HTML comments, but having some trouble getting it right (as seen in "[XPath to select between two HTML comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871618/xpath-to-select-between-two-html-comments)").
There seems to be a problem when new comments that are on the same line.

My HTML:

```
<html>
 ........
 <!-- begin content -->
 <div>some text</div>
 <div>
   <p>Some more elements</p>
 </div>
 <!-- end content --><!-- begin content -->
 <div>more text</div>
 <!-- end content -->
 .......
</html>
```

I use:

```
doc.xpath("//node()[preceding-sibling::comment()[. = ' begin content ']]
          [following-sibling::comment()[. = ' end content ']]")
```

Result:

```
<div>some text</div>
<div>
  <p>Some more elements</p>
</div>
<!-- end content --><!-- begin content -->
<div>more text</div>
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
<div>some text</div>
<div>
  <p>Some more elements</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the first pair of comments, you could start with looking for the first comment:

```
//comment()[.=' begin content ']/following::*[not(preceding::comment()[.=' end content '])]
```

I.e.:

```
//comment()[1][.=' begin content ']           <-- look for first suitable comment
    /following::*                             <-- take all following nodes
         [not(preceding::comment()[.=' end content '])] <-- satisfying condition there is no preceding "end comment"
```